# why do I need SharpSvn-DB44-20-win32 and SharpSvn-Sasl21-23-win32 as separate DLLs?

Tags: sharpsvn

I'm using SharpSVN as part of a FluentMigrator branch (to add in source control calls to FM). When I build, I find that these two assemblies are required to get the code to compile:

```
SharpSvn-DB44-20-win32
SharpSvn-Sasl21-23-win32
```

I'm wondering why these files aren't baked in as resources if they're needed. It seems odd to need to pull in 3 assemblies to get SharpSVN to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they're optional, and their license requires to be optional (otherwise Subversion and SharpSvn couldn't be Apache licensed).

It's likely that you need them at compile time, and they're optional at runtime.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered licensing. Thanks for clearing that up.